# Moving buttons via Touch

Tags: android, touch, android-button

I want to move my buttons to another palce with touch. I mean if user touch one button and go to another place via touch, the button moves. I write this code for one of buttons, but when i touch one button, three button moves as well as and one button cannot move to right or left and when i move to top of screen, a part of image button deleted!

What is the problem? and How can i solve this? I want run this program in android +2.2

```
onButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) oneButton.getLayoutParams();
                    int x=(int)event.getRawX();
                    int y=(int)event.getRawY();

                    relativeLayout.leftMargin=x-50;
                    relativeLayout.rightMargin=x-50;
                    relativeLayout.topMargin=y-50;
                    relativeLayout.bottomMargin=y-50;
                    oneButton.setLayoutParams(relativeLayout);
                    break;
                    default:
                        break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:src="@drawable/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/btnOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dip"
    android:src="@drawable/oneButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dip"
    android:src="@drawable/twoButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
   <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/btnThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnOne"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ThreeButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
   <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/btnFour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnTwo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/fourButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:visibility="invisible"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks....

Comment: Nobody is here that help me !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a new Class that implements OnTouchListener

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MultiTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{

private float mPrevX;
private float mPrevY;

public MainActivity mainActivity;
public MultiTouchListener(MainActivity mainActivity1) {
    mainActivity = mainActivity1;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    float currX,currY;
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            mPrevX = event.getX();
            mPrevY = event.getY();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {

                currX = event.getRawX();
                currY = event.getRawY();


                MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());   
                marginParams.setMargins((int)(currX - mPrevX), (int)(currY - mPrevY),0, 0);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 


            break;
        }



        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

Now in your Main activity, set OnTouchListener on your view... that is your imageButton or imageView;

```
MultiTouchListener touchListener=new MultiTouchListener(this);
onButton.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but again my program has problem :( When i touch and try to move to another place, btnFour move with btnOne(both together!! ) and when i touch btnTwo, btnThree move with this(but this happend first move before i touch btnThree and btnFour!) and i want when user click on the buttons, shows another activity, i implemented this with onClick() method but now with this code, onClick() method not work. What code i add to MultiTouchListener class for solve onClick()?? Thanks

Comment: Add the following in button tag in your XML , the button you want to click        
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: and another problem is when i move my buttons to bottom of screen or right of scrren, a part of my buttons deleted like part of buttons is under ImageView. Why? Have you any suggestion?

Comment: I add this code but my problems not solved. Again i touch my buttons not shows another activity and when i touch btnOne and btnTow first, btnFour and btnThree move with this ! I think my problem is in xml file but i dont know how can i solve this .

Comment: For the problem of ur button getting out of screen.. You can put some condition in MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: to check if your view is not going out of the screen. For this you can use if(currX< screenWidth) { view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); } , where screenWidth is the width of the device.  You have to get it through some code.. Similarly for the Y axis of the device..

Comment: for move two buttons together, i check if i delete layout_alignBelow, my problem solved, but my buttons shows in bottom of screen and i dont want this :( Why this happened?

Comment: Try using two relative Layouts,, one containing the above two buttons and another containing the below buttons and the aligning the IInd relative  Layout below the second one..

Comment: I will check this about 10-12 hours and if i have any question, i ask of you or i submit your answer :) Thanks

Comment: @SensorS Yes.. please do inform about any queries

Comment: Can you tell what `MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams( arg0.getLayoutParams());   
                 marginParams.setMargins((int)(  currentX  - mPrevX), (int)( currentY - mPrevY),0, 0);
                 LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                 arg0.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); ` is actually doing ?