# Move button back to origin after dragging/moving it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have an ImageButton that I need aligned to the bottom of the screen, and when I click and drag it, it moves with my finger by a certain distance, beyond which it will not move further from the origin but continue following the direction my finger is from the origin.

When I let go, the button has to slide back to the origin.

What I have managed to do so far is to have the button follow my finger via this answer: [Moving buttons via Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219216/moving-buttons-via-touch)

However, how should I get the origin of the button at initialization for it to bounce back after I release?

---

Originally I implemented the alignment of the button by having a android:layout_gravity="center|bottom" to place it at the bottom, but it somehow messes with the position of the button relative to my finger (It follows my finger movements but it's off center).

Hence, I used mButton.setY() and mButton.setX() to place it at the bottom of the screen, but it seemed hackish to use the screen dimensions to place it. Can't think of a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width and height of your layout in XML using 
`layout_width` and `layout_height`.

Then in your `MainActivity`, instantiate the layout (I will use LinearLayout as an example) and get its width and height.

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findviewbyid(R.id.l1);
int height = l.getHeight();
int width = l.getWidth();
```

Now, whenever you release the button, you can set your its position in the following way:

```
mButton.setY(height - 50)
```

This will position the ImageButton 50 pixels above the bottom of your layout. You can also set the `x` position of the button as you want in the same way. Also, you should probably store `height - 50` as a global variable (`origin`) that you can call from anywhere in your code.